# Connecting Apache Consumer to a single node on a Kafka Cluster

Tags: networking, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster on a private LAN, I want to have a consumer access the data on a different LAN, due to **network restrictions**, I can only access the main IP address (no DNS) of the cluster, let's call it *master-node*.

My consumer connects to the cluster without a problem, but the cluster instructs the consumer to fetch data from *node1*, *node2* and *node3*, which I do NOT have network access to.

Is there a way to ask the *master-node* to gather the data on behalf of my consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumers connect directly to the individual brokers which are leaders for individual partitions. This is to provide high scalability. By funnelling all traffic through a single endpoint, you are introducing a single point of failure.

If you need such a "proxy", then only option I am aware of would be the Kafka REST Proxy, and then you would have to consume and produce over HTTP rather than native Kafka clients.

Comment: There's also this, but seems to be work-in-progress https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy